# How to define form unique "id" attribute from a controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have a controller which create a several identical forms:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
   $infos[$i] = new Stuff();
   $forms[$i] = $this->createForm('StuffType', $infos[$i]);
   $forms[$i]->handleRequest($request);
}
```

The problem is that the 10 forms are using same IDs. I'm looking for a way to specify the ID for each form. I don't want to use the `$this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder` method as I want to use my (custom and reusable) `StuffType` form builder.

Except if I don't understand well, I can't use twig `attr` tweak neither as I want to be able to persist my forms:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
   $em->persist($infos[$i]);
}
```

Some Twig ID modification will specify an ID, but I won't be able to persist objects the way I currently do it. Or am I wrong?

Currently, this code runs but persists the same object 10 times. That's why I think it's an ID issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you would be better off using a form collection and then passing it an array of $stuffs.  You end up with one form and the persistence is handled more or less magically.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why you don't want to use `FormFactory::createNamedBuilder()` as this is the solution to your problem.

I takes one more argument than `createForm()`, as first and it's precisely the name (form html name attribute).

```
// From a controller extending \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
// in Symfony 2.7

$this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder(
    'stuff_form_'.$i, // will print <form name="stuff_form_1" ...
    'StuffType', // type alias
    $infos[$i], // data default to null
    $options // array if needed
);

// in Symfony 2.8+
$this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder(
    'stuff_form_'.$i,
    StuffType::class, // Full qualified name of class (FQCN)
    $infos[$i]
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you can pass the `type::class` like that, that's why I would have prefer to avoid createNamedBuilder. Your solution works great, IDs are now different. However, when I try to persist (when form is submitted), only the first `Stuff` entity get values ; others are NULL. Any idea?

Comment: Got it: I add to remove the `form_start` and `form_end` in my twig template (as forms are embedded).

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial explains how to embed a collection of forms properly:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

You can ignore the part about Prototype as you don't need to create new forms dynamically.

You can also set the form id from twig:

```
{{ form_widget(form, {'id':'yourid' }) }}
```

but i doubt it would solve your issue.